# assign new matrix values based on row and column index vectors

Tags: matlab, indexing

New to MatLab here (R2015a, Mac OS 10.10.5), and hoping to find a solution to this indexing problem.

I want to change the values of a large 2D matrix, based on one vector of row indices and one of column indices. For a very simple example, if I have a 3 x 2 matrix of zeros:

```
A = zeros(3, 2)

0 0
0 0
0 0
```

I want to change A(1, 1) = 1, and A(2, 2) = 1, and A(3, 1) = 1, such that A is now

```
1 0
0 1
1 0
```

And I want to do this using vectors to indicate the row and column indices:

```
rows = [1 2 3];
cols = [1 2 1];
```

Is there a way to do this without looping? Remember, this is a toy example that needs to work on a very large 2D matrix. For extra credit, can I also include a vector that indicates which value to insert, instead of fixing it at 1?

My looping approach is easy, but slow:

```
for i = 1:length(rows)

    A(rows(i), cols(i)) = 1;

end
```

Comment: Try [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[sub2ind](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) can help here,

```
A = zeros(3,2)
rows = [1 2 3];
cols = [1 2 1];

A(sub2ind(size(A),rows,cols))=1
A =

     1     0
     0     1
     1     0
```

with a vector to 'insert'

```
b = [1,2,3];
A(sub2ind(size(A),rows,cols))=b

A =

     1     0
     0     2
     3     0
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer online when checking on the speed of sub2ind.

```
idx = rows + (cols - 1) * size(A, 1);
```

therefore

```
A(idx) = 1 % or b
```

5 tests on a big matrix (~ 5 second operations) shows it's 20% faster than sub2ind.

There is code for an n-dimensional problem [here](http://tipstrickshowtos.blogspot.com/2010/02/fast-replacement-for-sub2ind.html) too.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is basically a sparse definition of a matrix. Thus, an alternative to [sub2ind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33760205/2732801) is `sparse`. It will create a sparse matrix, use `full` to convert it to a full matrix.

```
A=full(sparse(rows,cols,1,3,2))
```