# Update matrix, single column per row where row index is in vecor

Tags: matlab, octave

Is there a way to update different column in each row of matrix, where row indices are stored in vector.

**Example**

```
mx = zeros(10,10);
cols = [2 3 5 4 6 8 9 1 2 3]';
for i = 1:size(mx,1)
    mx(i,cols(i)) = 1;
end
mx
```

produces

```
0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

The question is, whether I can do it without the for loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [assign new matrix values based on row and column index vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33760043/assign-new-matrix-values-based-on-row-and-column-index-vectors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can address elements in a matrix with a single number. In this case the elements are numbered columnwise (1-10 is the first column, 11-20 the secound...) and there is a function `sub2ind` to calculate the element number for you. In your case its pretty easy, because its a 10x10 so you could do it manually, but i would still recommend the function.

```
mx = zeros(10,10);
rows = 1:size(mx,1); %create the row indices 
cols = [2 3 5 4 6 8 9 1 2 3];
X=sub2ind(size(mx),rows,cols)
mx(X)=1;
mx
```

Comment: Thank You, sub2ind is what I was looking for, the actual matrix is of course much larger than 10x10.